# how to change background color of google vr view fullscreen icon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

This is an image you see a full-screen icon
[image]

```js
window.addEventListener('load', onVrViewLoad);

      function onVrViewLoad() {
        var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
          image: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://d305uc8ofhou21.cloudfront.net/images/vrimage/vr_kitchen.jpg',
          width:'500px',
          height:'300px'});
      }
```

```html
<div id="vrview" class="view-image"></div>
```

Comment: Add some description about your problem.

Comment: That is `img` tag getting created with class `img.webvr-button`

Comment: how to change a background color of full-screen icon and check an image there is icon of fullscreen view .. i want to change a background color